# Display images stored in cache, Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-image

I download pictures from the Web and I stored them in the cache. Now, how I can display the photo in the XML. The photos stored as follwing:

/data/data/com.example.app/cache/wpta_i.jpeg

Changes according to the position. My XML is as following:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img"  
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center">      
    </ImageView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

How can I load the image from the cache and display it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load the drawable from code and then setImageDrawable to the ImageView.

```
String pathName = "/data/data/com.example.app/cache/wpta_i.jpeg"; 
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
ImageView myImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
myImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: hii can you tell me how can i clear the cache?? i have problem like that.i am getting the images from w/s but when the image is changed in w/s.i am getting the new images but can't show the new in place of old.so how can i clear cache?

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Context.getCacheDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) to get your cache directory and then access it from Code as shown in Perroloco's answer.

The documentation states a clear warning:

> **These files will be ones that get deleted first** when the device runs low on storage.
>
> There is no guarantee when these files will be deleted.

So make sure that your file exists prior to trying to load it.

Comment: This is a different question that has been answered many times, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10069679/422060).