# Save string as an image on device internal storage

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app that connects to facebook and save user's profile image on device internal storage.

This is my code:

```
private void getFacebookUserProfilePicture(String userAccessToken)
{
    String url = Constants.FB_PROFILE_IMAGE_URL + userAccessToken;

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response)
        {
            saveUserProfileImage(response.getBytes());
        }
    });
}
private void saveUserProfileImage(byte[] imageBytes)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Save user image");

    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    try
    {
        fOut = openFileOutput(Constants.FB_PROFILE_IMAGE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        fOut.write(imageBytes);
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm testing using Android emulator and I have used Eclipse DDMS to save the file to my PC, but I can't open it.

**What am I doing wrong?** I have saved with a jpg extension.

Or maybe, the question could be: **How can I save a `byte[]` as a JPG image?**

If I test the `url` on the browser, I get an image with **2,47KB**. And the image I have copied from the device is **4,26KB**.

Comment: have you got any error.??

Comment: No, I don't get any error.

Comment: First thing, you cant convert string to byte. you have to image which can convert into byte array..

Comment: *you have to image which can convert into byte array* What does it mean?

Comment: you have only string of image, but not image. if you have any image then we can convert into byte array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert string into byte array and then write this array to your filename.
You this method to write array:

```
public void WriteByteToFile(byte[] mybytes, String filename){

try {

FileOutputStream FOS = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
FOS.write(mybytes);
FOS.close();


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Convert string into byte array like below:

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Try it hopr this solve your problem..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added more details to my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100429/how-should-i-save-an-image-on-android). And after that you can check if it's loading image from device or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added more data to my question.