# How can I get informations within code about the cache of my app?

Tags: android, performance, caching, logging

I want to check where my apps cache is raising all the time. 
So I need a method to access informations about the current cache at any time. 
I think there must be such a method, because I could see the size of the cache in the App-Info of my android-smartphone.
The app is running in the background and I want to log when the size of the cache is raising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code snippets for your solution.

```
public static byte[] retrieveData(Context context, String name) throws IOException {

        File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        File file = new File(cacheDir, name);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            // Data doesn't exist
            return null;
        }

        byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            is.read(data);
        }
        finally {
            is.close();
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Here is complete **CacheManager** class.

[When to clear the cache dir in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942560/when-to-clear-the-cache-dir-in-android)