# How do I delete a file stored in cache? (android)

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I am not able delete file that is stored in cache. I am using the cache for several purposes. I am reading and writing but not able to delete. Can someone please help me with this?

```
//write
   public static void writeObject(Context context, String key, Object object)
                                  throws IOException {
            Log.d("Cache", "WRITE: context");
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(object);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
   }

//read
   public static Object readObject(Context context, String key) throws IOException,
         ClassNotFoundException {
      FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
      Object object = ois.readObject();
      return object;
   }

//delete
   public static void clearCahe(String key) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(key);
        file.delete();
   }
```

Comment: please log the return type of delete method . and please print stack trace might be particular file is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`context.openFileOutput(key` writes the file to internal memory. The path you can find with getFilesDir() and looks like `/data/data/<yourpackagename>/files`.

So if you want to delete the file 'key' you have to set up the path for `File file = new File(path)` as `String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + key;`.

And use file.exists() to check if the file exists!

Comment: can be defined like this; File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);

Answer (score 0):

use this to clear application data.

```
  public void clearApplicationData() 
    {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) 
    {
        if (dir != null &amp;&amp; dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Files**

Like the cache directory, your app also has an app-specific directory for holding files. Files in this directory will exist until the app explicitly deletes them or the app is uninstalled. You typically access this directory with `Context.getFilesDir()`. This can show up as various things on the app info screen, but in your screenshot this is "USB Storage Data".

**NOTE:** If you want to explicitly place on external media (typically SD card), you can use `Context.getExternalFilesDir(String type)`.

**Simple cache manager:**

```
public class CacheManager {

    private static final long MAX_SIZE = 5242880L; // 5MB

    private CacheManager() {

    }

    public static void cacheData(Context context, byte[] data, String name) throws IOException {

        File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        long size = getDirSize(cacheDir);
        long newSize = data.length + size;

        if (newSize > MAX_SIZE) {
            cleanDir(cacheDir, newSize - MAX_SIZE);
        }

        File file = new File(cacheDir, name);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            os.write(data);
        }
        finally {
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] retrieveData(Context context, String name) throws IOException {

        File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        File file = new File(cacheDir, name);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            // Data doesn't exist
            return null;
        }

        byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            is.read(data);
        }
        finally {
            is.close();
        }

        return data;
    }

    private static void cleanDir(File dir, long bytes) {

        long bytesDeleted = 0;
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            bytesDeleted += file.length();
            file.delete();

            if (bytesDeleted >= bytes) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static long getDirSize(File dir) {

        long size = 0;
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                size += file.length();
            }
        }

        return size;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The purpose of the cache is to cut down on network activity, 
long processes, and provide a responsive UI in your app.

Reference: [When to clear the cache dir in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942560/when-to-clear-the-cache-dir-in-android).