# How to delete cache

Tags: android, caching, internal-storage

How to delete cache from the cache folder  of the android phone from internal storage

using this code but it didn't worked for me

```
File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
if (files != null) {
for (File file : files)
file.delete();}
```

Comment: Have you added this in your manifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>`?

Comment: yeah but still it did'nt work for me

Comment: have you visited this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942560/when-to-clear-the-cache-dir-in-android  ?

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "didn't worked for me" means.

Comment: @user3475052 check my answer