# Xamarin.Android: Get filepath from CacheDir

Tags: android, xamarin, directory, xamarin.android, filepath

How do I get the filepath from the cache? Android: [`getCacheDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()) / Xamarin: [`CacheDir`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Content.Context.CacheDir/). I can't find any useful information on this ...

What is meant with the 1 MB size limit? Each file or the file size of all files in the cache directory? Where should one place temporary files which exceeds that limit? On the device's internal storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CacheDir` property returns a [Java.IO.File](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.IO.File/). This object has a property [AbsolutePath](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Java.IO.File.AbsolutePath/) that contains the path of the cache directory.

```
// e.g. in your activity
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(CacheDir.AbsolutePath);
    }
}
```

This 1MB is just an example. You can use more space. It is just a hint from google, to set a limit to yourself.
Here is a really nice answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10069679/1489968

Comment: Thanks for your answer. He doesn't recognize `CacheDir`. I can't build the app.

Comment: The name `CacheDir` doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: In wich context do you use it? I updated my example. You need to be in a scope of a `Context`, e.g. an `Activity`.

Comment: That's the reason. I'm implementing an interface and here I'm not in the scope of a `Context`. But I found a solution by accessing the `Context` in `MainActivity`.